# How can I use pygments over rough on Github Pages?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Github Pages have upgrade its Jekyll into 3.1.1, and the highlight configuration option in _config.yml has been renamed to "highlighter".
But here's the question, I use pygments in my configuration:

```
highlighter: pygments
```

but when I push my config file to github, it never works. It seems that the page is still using rough to print highlights.

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll highlighter is now rouge. Github pages available plugins list can be found here : https://pages.github.com/versions/ .

If you want to use pygments, you have to generate locally and then push resulting code to gh pages.

Comment: But when I use `highlighter: null`, the page generated by Github Pages is still using rough.

Comment: What is "rough" ?

Comment: sorry,spelling mistake...I mean rouge

Comment: github repository url please.